# ajax function broke on Blackberry OS/6

Tags: ajax, blackberry, bold, xui

I was using XUI javascript library for Blackberry web application (OS 4.7 and 5.0). I just tried code on Blackberry Bold with OS6.

Problem is that http ajax calls to remote server fail. No errors are shown, just calls do not work. Programs works 100% with Mozilla and IE on desktop and older Blackberry models.  Can anyone suggest a fix, or a better library?  I do not need GUI that jQueryMobile offers.

Comment: Can you post some of your code? Kind of asking us to look into a crystal ball without it.

Comment: I am more asking what people are using for ajax library on blackberry os6.